# Is there a way how to get total count of entities of given type in CRM without paging

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

Suppose I have query like

```
var countAlias = "entity_count";
var query = FormattableString.Invariant($@" 
  <fetch distinct='false' aggregate='true'> 
    <entity name='{entityName}'> 
      <attribute name='createdon' alias='{countAlias}' aggregate='count'/> 
    </entity> 
  </fetch>");

var response = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(query));
var entity = response.Entities.First();
var count = (int)((AliasedValue)entity[countAlias]).Value;
```

This works nicely unless there is more than 50K records - then it hits the aggregation limit.
Is there a way how to query total count of entities in system without paging ?

Comment: are you sure count can't handle more than 50k records? Cuz 50 is like nothing to a DB

Comment: @Steve - yup it is nothing DB-wise, but this is the limitation of FetchXml  - I actually hit this error; also check out https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/155623

Comment: @Steve There's a limit for Dynamics CRM. You can crank up this limit for an on-premise system but if it's a cloud instance you have no access to this setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, short answer is **No**.

Fetchxml is the only option to do aggregation like count, sum, etc - that too has 50k record limit due to [performance consideration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792525.aspx) (upper limit can be bent for on-prem).

Query expression, LINQ to CRM [doesn’t support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31559467/7920473) aggregation. That’s why we got paging cookie as a choice from MS to iterate & count the records.

Alternatively, (unlikely) if you have reporting replication sql DB by pushing a data sync, Rollup count can be done with some jobs in timely manner.